# How to get current cell in radScheduler

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik

this code above is part of my code. Using this code you can get the cell where is the cursor point but i want to get the selected/current cell independently where the cursor is. I dont understand how to use SelectionBehavior.CurrentCell and the SelectionBehavior. CurrentCellElement properties

```
Dim point As Point = Me.RadScheduler1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)

Dim groupedDayViewElement As TimelineGroupingByResourcesElement = TryCast(Me.RadScheduler1.SchedulerElement.ViewElement, TimelineGroupingByResourcesElement)
Dim cellElement As SchedulerCellElement = SchedulerUIHelper.GetCellAtPoint(point, groupedDayViewElement.GetTimelineElements())
If cellElement IsNot Nothing Then 
    Dim timelneViewElement As SchedulerTimelineViewElement = TryCast(cellElement.Parent.Parent, SchedulerTimelineViewElement)
```

Answer (score 0):

My VB.Net skills are very rusty but I converted a C# example of how to get the currently selected appointment:

```
Dim selectedAppt As AppointmentElement = SchedulerUIHelper.GetSelectedAppointment(Me.RadScheduler1);
Dim appt As Appointment = TryCast(selectedAppt.Appointment, Appointment);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. but this answer is right when you want to get the selected appointment in scheduler not the cell

Comment: Good call - Telerik controls are great but there are a lot different control objects and layers of them that are sometimes hard to navigate through to get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is:

```
If Me.RadScheduler1.SelectionBehavior.HasCellsSelected Then
        Dim cell = Me.RadScheduler1.SelectionBehavior.CurrentCellElement
    End If
```